# Ending of Social Network

Tags: analysis, ending, the-social-network

At the start Erica tells Mark

> "But you’re going to go through life thinking that girls don’t like you because you’re a nerd. And I want you to know, from the bottom of my heart, that that won’t be true. It’ll be because you’re an asshole."

At the end Marilyn tells Mark

> "You’re not an asshole, Mark. You’re just trying so hard to be."

When Mark waits on the reply from Erica and continuously refreshes the page, does this indicate that he believes that he can discount Erica's insult to him?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean if Mark with all his current might, money and status suspects to be able to turn Erica around on that point, then I think no, he does not believe that. He knows she is far too honest. However, I do think that he sincerely believes Erica still being capable of becoming friends with him, whether she changed her opinion or not.

I must admit the ending has a nice touch and it indeed raises this very question to the audience. But I am pretty sure this is just a nice side effect of Marilyn's comment because the film makers had to add a *Mark is nice*-element as requested by the real Zuckerberg.

Answer (score 15):

The ending depicts Mark's loneliness. He has given a website to the world which helps them connect to friends, but he himself is without any friends. At the end we see that he still hasn't forgotten his old girlfriend as he sends her friend request & refreshes the page continually to see when is it accepted. We see mark's desperation to make a connection. A real one.

Comment: (of course in real life, Mark was, throughout the whole of the time period depicted in the film, in a happy, successful relationship with the woman he'd go on to marry. But Holywood does love its "people who work in technology are lonely nerds" trope...)